# Android - how to set the wallpaper image

Tags: android, image, wallpaper

Is it possible to set the android wallpaper image programatically? I'd like to create a service that downloads an image from the web and updates the home screen wallpaper periodically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205092/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image/5813607#5813607 click this link I write there sample code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream(java.io.InputStream)) on the developer site:

```
public void setStream (InputStream data)
```

> Change the current system wallpaper to a specific byte stream. The give InputStream is copied into persistent storage and will now be used as the wallpaper. Currently it must be either a JPEG or PNG image.

Comment: Note that API first appeared in 2.0; if you want to support older versions, use one of the original APIs on Context:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setWallpaper(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: i tried same thing for videoistream...it's not working ...for imageurl it work fine...any idea/suggestion here.

Answer (score 32):

If you have image URL then use

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
InputStream ins = new URL("absolute/path/of/image").openStream();
wpm.setStream(ins);
```

If you have image URI then use

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
wpm.setResource(Uri.of.image);
```

In your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I tried same things for video stream..but I am getting --- "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" error...any suggestion here.

Comment: is it possible to set live wallpaper as an default wallpaper from application.

Comment: It must be a new Questions.. anyways what do you mean by default wallpaper?

Answer (score 5):

If you have bitmap of image than you will add this function to set as wallpaper:

```
  public void SetBackground(int Url) {

    try {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/sampleimage");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Url);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(file));
        Context context = this.getBaseContext();
        context.setWallpaper(bitmap);            
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper has been set",             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }         
}
```

you should add permission for this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 4):

OK Here's how to do it before api 2.0:

You need to call getApplicationContext.setWallpaper() and pass it the bitmap.

This method is now deprecated. See ChrisF's answer for details on the new method.