# How to set wallpaper in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - how to set the wallpaper image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image)

I hav started doing app in Android. I want to set wallpaer in Android which run in Background(using Service) and the wallpaper will change within 5 minute in background. I keep  the image files in Drawable. Anyone kindly send the coding for setting the wallpaer and retriving it after 5 minutes..

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SetWallpaperActivity.html). But unfortunately it does not work for me. Basically I am using the following code:

Code:

```
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(this);  
    String imageFilePath = getFilePath(imageUri);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
    if (myBitmap != null) {  
        try {  
            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap);  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            showToast(ImageDisplay.this,
                    "Failed to set Backgroundimage");  
        }  
    } else {  
        showToast(ImageDisplay.this, "Failed to decode image.");  
    }
```

The `imageFilePath` is correct as far as I can tell (as I also for different stuff that is working). There is no error or exception. The background of my phone is just empty after calling this app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
bitmap.recycle();
 if(imagePath!=null){
   System.out.println("Hi I am try to open Bit map");
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
```

................................................. if you have image URI then use this

```
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
mImageView.setImageURI(imagepath);
```

.............. Let me know if there is any issue .

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). 
Write a simple service and you could use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to change the Wallpaper at regular intervals.

Comment: I am unble to do this by following WallpaperManager.
Please help me..........

Comment: It would help if you could state why you can't use WallpaperManager. What API level are you targeting?