# android set image as contact icon/wallpaper

Tags: android, image, viewer

I have written my own ImageViewer and now I want to have **Set as** functionality like in Android native ImageViewer. I now it is possible since Facebook has it. I've attached a screenshot to make myself more clear. [image]

P.S. I want to give a more detailed explanation of what goes wrong. After I choose "Contact icon" in the menu the list of my contacts appears. When I choose a contact the application force closes. If I choose "Home/Lock screen wallpaper" it opens my phone's gallery.
Here is my code snippet:

```
                Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
                Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                setAs.setType("image/jpg");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/my_tmp_file.jpg");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {                       
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setAs.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/my_tmp_file.jpg"));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Set Image As"));
```

I have also added the consequent permissions to my manifest and I am able to write my image to the sd card of the phone.

[image: LogCat Output]

Comment: you will have to send an intent. it is simple. all you have to do is search for some code on editing a contact and on changing the wallpaper programatically

Comment: I can't find code which will open OptionsMenu like in native ImageViewer. And after that when I choose an action it should continue like native. It is easier to do either, but I can't do what I need.

Comment: Can you give us a logcat error output?

Comment: Ok. I've add it to my question.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error as text?

Comment: Which text do you mean? RuntimeException or ActivityNotFoundException?

Comment: 09-05 13:48:49.465: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(730): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP (has extras) }

Answer (score 4):

From the [Google Gallery app source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery):

```
// Called when "Set as" is clicked.
private static boolean onSetAsClicked(MenuInvoker onInvoke,
                                      final Activity activity) {
    onInvoke.run(new MenuCallback() {
        public void run(Uri u, IImage image) {
            if (u == null || image == null) {
                return;
            }

            Intent intent = Util.createSetAsIntent(image);
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    activity.getText(R.string.setImage)));
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

From Utils.java

```
// Returns an intent which is used for "set as" menu items.
public static Intent createSetAsIntent(IImage image) {
    Uri u = image.fullSizeImageUri();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.setDataAndType(u, image.getMimeType());
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", image.getMimeType());
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what is IImage. Eclipse gives no appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Looks like it's just an interface - `fullSizeImageUri` is defined as `public abstract Uri fullSizeImageUri();` so it's just returning a `Uri` to the image

Comment: I'll try to find more about getMimeType and will try your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. I get a popup with this "No application can perform this action". but thanks anyway.

Comment: This stopped working with new Google Photos app. Workaround seems to be really tacky

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the contacts app code. There is an `AttachImage` activity that launches for attaching an image. The icon photo should be 96x96 px dimension. The `action...CROP` does face detection and cropping on the image you pass.

Link : [AttachImage.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/AttachImage.java)

You should scale and crop the image to 96x96 and pass its URI to the `insertPhoto` method used in `AttachImage` activity.
For changing wallpaper you can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1964193/857361)'s answer.

### Update

Code for launching cropping activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP", myIntent.getData());
if (myIntent.getStringExtra("mimeType") != null) {
   intent.setDataAndType(myIntent.getData(), myIntent.getStringExtra("mimeType"));
}
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO);
```

Comment: What is the difference in your requirement

Comment: as far as I could get these link allow either to attach image to contact or to set it as a wallpaper. Besides I want to open the native cropping page and not to crop the image programmatically. I want this to work just like the native.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll to combine these all and get the result I want.

Comment: the link AttachImage.java is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) to set the wallpaper.

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Comment: This works best on all devices, resolutions and OS versions (ignoring 2.0-)
No cropping available with this approach though :/

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
File externalFile=new File("filePath");
Uri sendUri = Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/jpg");
            intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set As"), 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Set image as (Contact,wallpaper,etc.)

```
        Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        setAs.setType("image/jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "/my_tmp_file.jpg");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setAs.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/my_tmp_file.jpg"),
                "image/jpg");
        setAs.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Set Image As"));
```

This will solve your problem and set the image as (Contact,Wallpaper,etc..)

Comment: i have tried to implement this method it works on bringing up the chooser but then fails to load the image, any ideas?

Comment: hi @martinseal1987 in which android version fails to load image please describe me....