# How to start the "set as" intent (wallpaper, contact picture, etc)

Tags: android, android-intent, wallpaper

I searched over the web during the last few weeks (seriously) but I can't find what I need. I just would like to start an intent corresponding to the **set as** action. It generally offers either **Set as wallpaper** or **Set as contact picture**. And then, if more application are installed on the device, they can be listed as well.

Here is an example of what I want :

[image]

I precise that I need to support API level 14 and higher.
I found [getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(android.net.Uri))  but it works only with **content URI** which is a problem for me, and is only availbable on API lvl 19 and higher.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android set image as contact icon/wallpaper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284142/android-set-image-as-contact-icon-wallpaper)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer by my self :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("jpg", "image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
getString(R.string.set_as)), REQUEST_ID_SET_AS_WALLPAPER);
```

You just have to ensure that the uri is public and will be reachable by the crop application chosen by the user.

Comment: It is working well for setting the wallpaper with Home Screen option but it is not working well while setting the wallpaper for Lock Screen Option. Why?

Comment: Lock Screen wallpapers are not part of Android Stock. It's usually added by smartphone manufacturers. Therefore, I think it's up to the manufacturer to add the lockscreen option to this intent. There's maybe a parameter to set to take this into account but nothing I know.

Comment: Is there any alternative code that is function same in react native ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me with Uri:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        intent, "Set as:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
//can't use normal URI, because it requires the Uri from file
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(uriOfImage)),"image/*");
intent.putExtra("mimeType","image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set Image"));
```

You can check that the URI that you pass, should contain the 'file://' prefix (It doesn't work without that).

Comment: Can't be done with FileProvider.getUriForFile ?? It does not work for me!