# How to open set as wallpaper intent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri, start-activity

I am trying to open a default intent of android gallery (screenshot given below).

for this i have referred some 
SO Questions but none of them are worked for me [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent) and [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663232/how-to-start-the-set-as-intent-wallpaper-contact-picture-etc)

here's a screenshot what i want...[samsung device's gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaZjw.png)

this is a working app on playstore..[wallpaperApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.offline.hd.wallpaper1234)

can Anyone please tell me how can i achieve this?

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: what is the error then?

Comment: a dialog appears with a message:"unable to find application to perform this action"

Answer (score 0):

You can use wallpaper manager to set image as wallpaper.

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
     myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }});
```

Comment: no , i don't want to use wallpaper manger  cause from this i can set my wallpaper at home screen only while open that intent will let user to set picture as home screen , lockscreen ,crop etc. so my question is how can i open that intent?

Comment: @Tarun Voora The question was another, i have updown this answer.