# Unable to set picture as. "No appps can perform this action"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-menu, android-wallpaper

I am trying to give users an option to set image as wallpaper/whatsapp dp like this.
[image]

But I'm stuck with this code

```
Uri sendUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.a_day_without_thinking_mobile);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/jpg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set As"));
```

It shows a dialog that no apps can perform this action. 
I also tried to check my Uri through this method

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cur = cr.query(sendUri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cur != null) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String filePath = cur.getString(0);

                if (new File(filePath).exists()) {
                    Log.d("URI: ","File path exist");
                } else {
                    Log.d("URI: ","File not found");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("URI: ","URI ok but no enty found");
            }
            cur.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("URI: ","URI was invalid for some other reason");
        }
```

And It always returned that the URI was invalid. But I'm sure that the image is valid jpg and is present in raw folder.
I tried changing URI paths but to no success.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: When I select the option it shows "No apps can perform this action". 
I think maybe it is due to proper image URI not loading.

Comment: Actually do you want to attach / post the file to the social media. is this correct ?

Comment: No, I want to give options to users to set the image as wallpaper. As shown in the above pic. But that dialog Isn't popping up Instead it is showing me a message that 'no apps can perform this action'.

Comment: so From your app, you are capturing the picture and you want that picture to be used to kept as DP for social medias as mentioned above

Comment: Image is already present inside the raw folder. I want to use that image which can be used to be set as wallpaper/dp. Kind of a wallpaper app only the images will not be on the server but inside the raw folder.

Comment: Not sure if there is an option to set wallpaper from the app. Mostly Intent are used to share the images to the respective medias.

Comment: But then how does wallpaper apps works. They also provide an option to set an image as wallpaper from within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Android file read format has been changed after `targetSdkVersion >= 24`

You can find the details here;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/1367450