# Modify current wallpaper

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, wallpaper

Is it possible to modify the current wallaper via code?
I'm getting the current wallpaper trough

```
WallpaperManager wpm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(myContext);
Drawable draw=wpm.getDrawable();
```

then I try to desaturate it with

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);    
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
draw.setColorFilter(filter);
```

then i create the bitmap and i try to set it as wallpaper trough

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)draw).getBitmap();
try {
      wpm.setBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it doesn't do anything.
I also tried with

```
myContext.setWallpaper(bitmap);
```

but it neither works.
I already have the permissions to change the wallpaper, so I cannot find my mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - how to set the wallpaper image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image)

Comment: that's not the problem: i already tried to change the wallpaper using a custom bitmap and it works with my code

Comment: Try displaying the transformed bmp on an ImageView?

Comment: yep, that would be the correct way if i could make he user notice the change