# How to change Wallpapers Programmatically?

Tags: android, wallpaper

Can I change the Installed wallpapers by their Package names?

For example:

```
String packageName = "com.wallpaper.livewallpaper";

start(packageName);
```

Comment: asked many times ... short story: image yes, live wallpaper no...

Comment: what about after opening the Live Wallpaper chooser? Can I somehow programmatically choose some of the wallpapers and set them for preview or Apply them?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
  intent.setClassName("com.android.wallpaper.livepicker",
    "com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperActivity");
  startActivity(intent);` <= it may or **may not** working since is not documented ... just pick android os source code and find folder "packages\wallpapers\LivePicker" there should be source of LivePicker ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - how to set the wallpaper image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, Android - how to set the wallpaper image is for Wallpaper image and not for Live Wallpaper. I am looking for a way to skip the Wallpaper Chooser, and set the LiveWallpaper directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing Live Wallpaper Programmatically in Android is not possible cause of the System Security Issues.