# Can i insert a some code in HTML to set android wallpaper

Tags: java, android, html, wallpaper

This would be my first post ever on stackoverflow.com 
I have found many many of the answers to my questions but this one question i cannot figure out.
I know that it is possible to invoke few android commands via either java code or other html code and was wondering if it is possible for a my website to set an image on my site as their wallpaper on their android phone. 
To better explain this is what im doing. 
My website will have say for example 50 images of something and when the user clicks on one of those photos the website will ( if possible ) invoke the android " set as background " Process. 
Currently it is set to just download to their phone and then the user goes and selects the photo as their wallpaper from their download folder on their phone.

Thank You in advance 
Vick S.

Comment: If there is a way my hunch is it would be a vulnerability in the browser.

Comment: You can't do it from a web page, but you can do it from a native (java) android application. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image if you are interested in the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  In Android, java runtime environment is what being run inside OS, and in order to execute commands you wish to make, rooting to OS is only way, and this can be done in java.  So, if I were in your shoes, I'd drop the idea of rooting command line to android via HTML - but look over onto java side.

In other words...yes, it is possible.  But, end-users will already have their phone/mobile pre-set to guard against that rooting commands, but to ask for permission from owner.  If owner clicked yes, then you are in game.  The hardest part about this is the complexity requiring bunches of efforts to code such rooting functions.

But, this could something as a starting point, at least? [Running Shell commands though java code on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android)

Good luck!

Comment: I would love to be able to do that but i am not familiar with java so that is kinda out of my league. But thanks for the reply, i appreciate it.

Comment: @Faron setting the wallpaper can be done from java via the public APIs there is no need to root. instructing the OP to root is just complicating things.

Comment: FoamyGuy - I am really glad you mentioned the public APIs and it saved my "headache of effort" in coding rooting.  Thanks dude!