# Android wallpaper on multiple devices

Tags: java, android, mobile, crop

I would like to set a wallpaper from the gallery.
The selected image will have to use the CropImage class of the device.

The problem is that every device have a different CropImage class, so when im using "Crop" action, the CropImage of the device opens, but not all set as a wallper.

Code:

```
Intent cropperIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP", chosenImageUri);
        cropperIntent.setDataAndType(chosenImageUri, "image/*");

        cropperIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("aspectX", outSize.x);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("aspectY", outSize.y);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("outputX", outSize.x);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("outputY", outSize.y);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("width", outSize.x);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("height", outSize.y);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
        cropperIntent.putExtra("set-as-wallpaper", true); // for: com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage
        cropperIntent.putExtra("setWallpaper", true); // for: com.android.camera.CropImage
```

For some devices its not set as wallpaper at all (Like HTC). Maybe have to set another extra like the  "set-as-wallpaper" and "set-as-wallpaper"...

Is there a generic method to set the wallpaper with it's cropper for all devices?

Comment: Try putting `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" >` `</uses-feature>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` for an instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is bound to not work on some phones, like HTC because they use their own gallery/camera. For those devices, you can just use an uncropped image, as a separate resource. However, if you have bitmap of image than you will add this function to set as wallpaper:

```
  public void SetBackground(int Url) {

    try {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/sampleimage");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Url);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(file));
        Context context = this.getBaseContext();
        context.setWallpaper(bitmap);            
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper has been set",             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }         
}
```

you should add permission for this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

This is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image/10185732#10185732).