# How to set the phone wallpaper through an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wallpaper

I have some images saved on the phone internal storage in a filepath that looks like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/myApp/FILENAME.jpg
```

I want to open an intent so that the user can set the phone wallpaper with his app of choice. Every code I tried doesn't work at all or only works with some apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set any image in sdcard or phone by opening this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Wallpaper"));
```

kindly add permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

for more options check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952137/5080229)

**P.S:** You need to add permission for SET_WALLPAPER for android 6+

## Update:

You can also open set wallpaper as dialog using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("jpg", "image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
getString(R.string.set_as)), REQUEST_ID_SET_AS_WALLPAPER);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use WallpaperManager, the wallpaper should be set for example through GooglePhotos or the phone's Launcher

Comment: You can no longer set wallpaper using [GooglePhotos](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/624vkl/can_no_longer_set_wallpaper_using_google_photos/)

Comment: yes I can, for example now i'm using QuickPic to set a wallpaper through Google Photos. I don't know how to do the same in my app.

Comment: Your code opens the intent dialog successfully but when I click on an app the app doesn't start.

Comment: I have found a solution